# how to detect silverlight plugin settings from silverlight application at run time?

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that can run well only if users set his Safari/Firefox Silverlight plug-in to "Run in unsafe mode". Despite it is already stated in the application FAQs/help section, many users still forget to set their Silverlight plug-in to "run in unsafe mode".

My question is: Is there a way to detect this from the application, i.e., detecting the browser's security setting from the Silverlight application? If my application detects that users not setting "run in unsafe mode", my application should give a warning.

Let me know if anyone has done this in the past.

Thank you,
Ann